# jQuery: how do I check if an element attribute contains part of a string?

Tags: jquery

Like, I want to check if a link has a certain domain, or already has parameters attached to the end.

is there a way of doing a regex thing like ~= maybe?

currently, I have

```
    alert(ref);
        $j("a[href*='mysite']").each(function(i){
            alert("hello");
            $j(this).attr('href',$j(this).attr('href') + "?ref=" + $j.cookie.get("tb_ref"));
        });
```

but the selector isn't working. (I never see the `Hello` alert, but I seed the `alert ref` alert.

my a tags

```
<a href="http://domain.mysite.com/">yeah, link</a>
<a href="http://google.com/">g, link</a>
```

Comment: Updated my answer based upon your code update.  The selector works for my code - maybe there's another problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [substring/contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector:

`$("selector[name*='mystring']")`

*finds attribute name="somemystring"*

If you're looking for the whole word, delimited by spaces, then use the [whole word selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/):

`$("selector[name~='mystring']")`

*finds attribute name="some mystring is good"*

**EDIT** I took your code from above and created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WgWM3/1/) for it.  I see the one 'Hello' alert pop-up.  (I didn't do an alert for the `alert(ref)`, as I didn't know what `ref` was.)  So the selector works for your `href` attributes.  You're alising jQuery different than normal (normal = `$`, you're using `$j`).  Did you register this alias properly?  If you use `$` or `jQuery` instead, does your code work then?

Comment: almost, i'll update my question to show you what I have so far. I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) (`*=`), like this:

```
$("a[href*=somedomain.com]")
```

There are [other attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) available as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the link is `<a id='link' href='www.google.com/myparam'></a>` and you want to tell if the link contains `myparam` use jQuery/javascript:

```
/myparam/.test($("#link").attr('href'))
```